# Is there any way I can add an aggregate to my code since there is a window function and I welcome any help on adjustments on the code as well

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT 
    `f.title`, 
    `c.name`, 
    `f.rental_duration`, 
    NTILE(4) over (ORDER BY f.rental_duration) AS `standard_quartile` 
FROM 
    `film_category` b 
JOIN 
    category c ON `c.category_id` = `b.category_id` 
JOIN 
    film f ON `f.film_id` = `b.film_id` 
WHERE 
    `c.name` IN ('Animation', 'Children', 'Comedy', 'Family', 'Music') 
ORDER BY 
    `f.rental_duration`;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-aggregate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sample-database/  link to sample database. And i want to sum the output of the rental_duration and standard_quartile

Comment: @IsraelOwusuAnsah Summing two values does not require a custom aggregate function.

Comment: I'm using postgresql instead please

Comment: you need to provide sample data and desired output , edit your question and add those information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query would be correct if only it was written according to the Postgres syntax. We do not use backticks in Postgres.

```
SELECT 
    f.title, 
    c.name, 
    f.rental_duration, 
    NTILE(4) over (ORDER BY f.rental_duration) AS standard_quartile 
FROM 
    film_category b 
JOIN 
    category c ON c.category_id = b.category_id 
JOIN 
    film f ON f.film_id = b.film_id 
WHERE 
    c.name IN ('Animation', 'Children', 'Comedy', 'Family', 'Music') 
ORDER BY 
    f.rental_duration;
```